# how to whitelist ONLY AWS services trying to use ssh (port 22) to perform actions that I execute in the AWS dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, whitelist

I would like to turn off access to ssh on my ec2 instances because I edit them using Cloud9 and it appears that AWS automatically enables access to the instances for Cloud9 without having to leave port 22 explicitly open for Cloud9. It does seem necessary to initially open port 22 to accomplish some of the initialization steps, but following that I am able to remove the ssh access and, at least partially, run the instance and edit it through Cloud9.

However, certain AWS functions do appear to require continued access to the instance to accomplish their tasks.

Does AWS publish a list or range of ipAddresses that they use to perform actions that you as the user initiate through the dashboard?

It seems to me that this would be an ENORMOUS improvement to security instead of leaving port 22 open to  the whole world.

Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: What are those "certain AWS functions" that need access to SSH?

Comment: @Parsifal that is an excellent question and in trying to pin down an answer to it, I discovered that I was apparently too quick to say that AWS "automatically enables access to the instances for Cloud9 without having to leave port 22 explicitly open for Cloud9" because, in fact, it does not appear in spite of this:   
---- 

< https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ip-ranges.html>

Comment: So I guess my question now is:   how do i get the ipAddress range that AWS uses even for Cloud9????  So i don't have to leave port 22 wide open??